# Chef - Unable to configure service resource to reload when a template resource is modified

Tags: chef-infra

I totally do not get the workflow for installing a service where the
init.d file is not installed.  Below is my recipe for installing
supervisor.  Also below in the error on boostrap.  I have the init.d
and config file as templates.  So, how do I adjust the logic to get
chef to work?

```
ec2-175-41-185-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Thu, 17 May
2012 22:18:02 +0000] ERROR: Running exception handlers
ec2-175-41-185-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Thu, 17 May
2012 22:18:02 +0000] FATAL: Saving node information to
/var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
ec2-175-41-185-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Thu, 17 May
2012 22:18:02 +0000] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
ec2-175-41-185-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Thu, 17 May
2012 22:18:02 +0000] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to
/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
ec2-175-41-185-174.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [Thu, 17 May
2012 22:18:02 +0000] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: service[supervisord]
(supervisor::default line 23) had an error: Errno::ENOENT: No such
file or directory - /etc/init.d/supervisord restart



easy_install_package "supervisor" do
 action :install
end

template "/etc/supervisord.conf" do
 path "/etc/supervisord.conf"
 source "supervisord.conf.erb"
 owner "root"
 group "root"
 mode "0600"
end

template "/etc/init.d/supervisord" do
 path "/etc/init.d/supervisord"
 source "supervisord.erb"
 owner "root"
 group "root"
 mode "0755"
 #notifies :start, "service[supervisord]", :immediately
end

service "supervisord" do
 supports :restart => true, :start => true, :stop => true, :reload => true
 action [ :enable]
 subscribes :start, resources(:template =>
"/etc/init.d/supervisord"), :immediately
end
```

Comment: Did I miss anything in your situation in my answer? Anything I could do to improve it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue here is due to your use of *:immediately* in your *notifies* and *subscribes* attributes.

When you use *:immediately* the notification is run immediately, which makes sense in some cases, but in this case the resource you are notifying or to which you are subscribing may not yet exist due to how Chef performs execution.

By default, [notifications are](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#notifications) are *:delayed* which means they are queued up to be triggered and are executed at the end of a Chef run. They then can be delivered to the [services](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#service) and other resources you want to notify.

For your example above, I would modify things as follows:

```
template "/etc/supervisord.conf" do
 path "/etc/supervisord.conf"
 source "supervisord.conf.erb"
 owner "root"
 group "root"
 mode "0600"
 notifies :reload, "service[supervisord]", :delayed
end

template "/etc/init.d/supervisord" do
 path "/etc/init.d/supervisord"
 source "supervisord.erb"
 owner "root"
 group "root"
 mode "0755"
 notifies :reload, "service[supervisord]", :delayed
end

service "supervisord" do
 supports :restart => true, :start => true, :stop => true, :reload => true
 action :enable
end
```

The above code does the following:

- Creates the supervisord configuration file and then notifies supervisord to reload at the end of the Chef run
- Creates the supervisord init.d script and then notifies supervisord to reload at the end of the Chef run
- Declares the supervisord service resources, supporting restart, start, stop, and reload, and enables it after any of those have run

See [The Chef Run](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html) or the older, but in some ways still more clear [Anatomy of a Chef Run](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Anatomy+of+a+Chef+Run) for more information on how Chef executes a run list and the cookbooks in a run list.